# "Install" button is disabled in Ubuntu (12.04 LTS) Software Center

Tags: 12.04, installation, software-center

Until recently, I was able to download and install applications directly from the Software Center but now since the past few days, the "Install" button is disabled at all times when I try and get an application. "sudo apt-get" works fine, but I would like to have the option of installing stuff directly from the Software Center.

The screenshots below will make things clearer:
(As you will observe in both snaps, the Install button is disabled...)

[image: Ubuntu Software Center screenshot for installing PlayOnLinux]

[image: Ubuntu Software Center screenshot for installing KeePassX]

I recently installed Ubuntu and have been encountering this problem since day 2. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a Dell Inspiron 15R 64-bit. Please someone help me out with this. Thanks in advance :D

Comment: try re-installing software center ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here...

Canonical had a server break-in about a week ago.  (You'll notice that ubuntu forums are "down for maintenance" even as I post, while they do damage control.)

I suspect that they also don't currently trust their archive and have taken it down until they can be sure it isn't loading malware on unsuspecting users.

If that's the case, being able to install via sudo apt-get may indicate that they took down the support for the gui tool but forgot to disable the underlying archive service.  You may be loading potentially corrupted software packages that they didn't intend you to be able to access.

If I were in your position I'd stop using anything you installed via apt-get (not uninstalling because it might have a corrupted uninstall mechanism) and hold off on reinstalling until they've vetted the archive - or at least explained it more thoroughly.  Then I'd consider rebuilding the system from scratch, depending on what they say about their findings, and certainly take any mitigating measures they prescribe.